# SendGrid API v3 using NodeJS @sendgrid/client - Call is Unauthorized / API Key is valid with full permissions

Tags: node.js, unauthorized, sendgrid-api-v3

I'm really struggling with a problem where every call I make to the @sendgrid/client comes back unauthorized.  The exact same key can be used with @sendgrid/mail in the same code and it works fine.

I've tried everything but cannot get the NodeJS @sendgrid/client to work.  I've even tried a brand new API Key and still get unauthorized.

I'm trying to use the /suppressions API.  I can make the exact same call, with the same API key, in Postman and it works fine.

What am I doing wrong here?

Here is my code:

```
    sgApiKey = config.get('sendGrid_APIKey');
    sgClient.setApiKey(sgApiKey);
    
    const email = "test@abc.com";
    const headers = {
    "on-behalf-of": "The subuser's username. This header generates the API call as if the subuser account was making the call."
    };

    const request = {
        url: `/v3/asm/suppressions/global/${email}`,
        method: 'GET',
        headers: headers
    }
    
    sgClient.request(request)
    .then(([response, body]) => {
        console.log(response.statusCode);
        console.log(response.body);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

I have tried creating a new API key with full permissions and it still does not work.

I'm expecting that my existing API key I already use for emailing should work to all the /suppression API.

Comment: I tried this exact same thing in C# with my API and it works perfectly.  I think something is up with the NodeJS client with the following URL - /v3/asm/suppressions/${email}

Comment: Did you ever figure what the issue was @Brett?

Comment: Have you tried a curl command to see if you receive the same error? `curl -X "GET" "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/asm/suppressions/global/<email>" -H "Authorization: Bearer <api-key>" -H "Content-Type: application/json"`

Comment: Hi forrestDinos, I never did end up getting it working.  I decided to put it behind our .NET C# REST API since it worked in C# and then I call that API from Node.  Not ideal for most NodeJS developers but for us it was ok because we are moving away from NodeJS anyway.

I wish I had more information for you.  I did not try it in curl.